# {be verb} + {subject}

Tags: ellipsis, inversion

> Written by people more or less knowledgeable about the subject and about the history of technology, these accounts tend to focus on the unusual and the spectacular, **be it** people or lines of research, and they often cede to the self-evaluation of their subjects.

This is a sentence excerpted from a history article by Michael S. Mahoney, "The History of Computing in the History of Technology."

What I cannot understand is the part of "be it people or lines of research". I know that 'be' and 'it' are inverted and that there is an ellipsis, but I don't know why and what is omitted.

Comment: I think that your question has already been answered here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/what-does-be-it-mean-in-this-passage

Comment: This is sometimes called an 'exhaustive conditional' construction, more specifically one where the subordinate clause has the subjunctive form. It's a formal alternant of the _whether_ construction, with _be_ and inversion instead of a subordinator. Compare "whether it be people or lines of research", or the non-subjunctive "whether it is people or lines of research".

Answer (score 1):

"Be it" is an example of the subjunctive mood. The subjunctive is very uncommon in modern English, and its rarity often leads to confusion about it, even among native English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

"Be it" is not commonly used in spoken English, though I've seen it often in writing. The meaning is essentially the same as "Whether" or "Whether it be" in this context.